# Moving slider during a certain time

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer, uislider, nstimeinterval

I have a slider with 96 slots and I need to moves slider step by step from 0 to 95 in 60 seconds. Should I use NSTimer with interval (60/96) and 96 repeats or there is a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably the best approach.  The `NSTimer` should behave fairly consistently at that interval, it only starts to get unreliable when calling it around every 1/10th second, or faster.

However, a bit of explanation in case it doesn't quite behave as you'd hoped:

It won't be perfect because the `NSTimer` doesn't have it's tick event *literally* every interval.  Rather, the `NSTimer` is at the mercy of it's thread's run-loop, which may not get around to calling your `@selector` method until a while after its interval has expired. Then combine that with calling for screen updates which are also not lock-step.

It's accuracy will mostly depend on what else you're doing in your run-loop... if there's not much going on in your device's little brain, then your slider should appear to move just as you'd hoped.

Edit: You may also consider an NSTimer with a longer interval, and use the UIView's animateWithDuration... methods to make it appear smooth?

Answer (score 1):

```
            aTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

            NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
            [runner addTimer:aTimer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

        - (void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)theTimer {

                  slider.maximumValue=totaltime;

                if(slider.value ==totaltime)
                { 
                    [theTimer invalidate];
                   //terminate the loop
        }
    else
    {
    slider.value=slider.value+1;
    }
    }

//timer runs continuously run if condition is true
```

Comment: NSTimer doesn't have an `isinValid` method.